# How to make xTicks fit into all the plot window?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, matlab-figure

In the plot below how can I make the xTicks fit into all the x axis? I can not understand where the problem is and I will appreciate any advice as a new MATLAB user. [image]
here is the part of code where I plot this graph :

```
    f=figure();
    plot(time, C, 'b*');
    hold on
    plot(time, L_Tilde, 'g-.');
    plot(time, U_Tilde, 'g-.');
    tickStep = 1 ;
    tickDates = datenum( 1996:tickStep:2007 ,1,1) ; 
    set(gca, 'XTick' , tickDates , 'XTickLabel' , datestr(tickDates,'yyyy') )
```

Comment: add `set(gca,'Ylim',[1996,2007])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the `ylimit`:

```
set(gca,'Xlim',[1996,2007])
set(gca, 'XTick' , tickDates , 'XTickLabel' , datestr(tickDates,'yyyy') )
```

[**Danny's suggestion**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26280016/2605073) is the automized way. To ge the **1996** back, you can add some days of margin to both sides:

```
%// example data
time = datenum( linspace(1996,2007),1,1);
L_Tilde = randi(10,[1,numel(time)]);

figure(1);
plot(time, L_Tilde, 'g-.');
tickStep = 1 ;
tickDates = datenum( 1996:tickStep:2007 ,1,1) ; 
xlimms = get(gca,'Xlim');
axis tight
set(gca, 'XLim', get(gca,'XLim')+[-100,+100])
set(gca, 'XTick' , tickDates , 'XTickLabel' , datestr(tickDates,'yyyy') )
```

[image]

Adjust the `100` according to your needs.

Comment: didn't you mean the `XLim`

Comment: Exactly! I was about saying that this way I have just empty plots with some dates on Y axis .

Comment: trying with both Xlim and Ylim I obtain just empty plots .

Comment: something strange is happening! this way all the points and  dates are concentrated at the center of the plot .

Comment: oh yes... thats because you're working with datenum. I haven't considered that. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried it on my data it's a great solution, but another strange thing is that still 1996 doesn't appear . Maybe I should give up and leave it this way.It's strange that your output shows 1996 but mine not!

Comment: for further help you need to share your data.

Comment: solved it! I've changed the 100 and everything is perfect. thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

> > axis tight

This will will set the limits of both axes to exactly the limits of the data.

Comment: just one thing this way 1996 will disappear , is there anyway to keep also 1996?

Comment: @Singu my way or after you've done what is suggested in this answer: `set(gca,'Xlim',get(gca,'Xlim').*[0.95,1.05])`, have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Indeed, the answer of thewaywewalk would be needed if you want to specify limits.